# ARCamera missing components unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have some problem with ARCamera. I've installed Unity 5.6.03f. I imported Vuforia package from Unity Assets store. Than dragged ARCamera from prefabs folder & it's missing a lot of component. How can i fix this? I also tried downloading Vuforia package from Unity website & than importing it but also have same results. During import I'm prompted to do API update

This is how my ARCamera looks like. Also I can't attach those components manually to ARCamera because scripts are missing from package.

There are a lot of questions on Vuforia forum regarding this but no one has got any reply or support

[image: My Vuforia]

What the ARCamera should look like

[image]

Comment: What is exactly missing? because I see nothing wrong with the `ARCamera`.

Comment: Did you try clicking the Open Vuforia Configuration button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Click on the *Open Vuforia Configuration* button. This is a change from Vuforia SDK v6.2.6 version. [Release notes here.](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Release_Notes/Vuforia-SDK-Release-Notes)

Comment: but where's the documentation for newer changes? I can only find old documentation. It doesn't have Load Data Set option in components